# How to get the currently logged in username from a remote computer

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, networking, winsock

Is there a way to get the currently logged in username from a remote computer? (I'm looking for something along the line of getUserName())

I've got a solution that kinda works but (to be brutally honest) feels like killing a fly with a cruise missile shot from a skateboard (complicated, definitely taking to long and probably overkill).

My solution (so far):

```
QString NetworkHandle::getUserName(QString entry){
    QString s1, s2, command;
    std::string temp, line;
    const char *cmd;
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    FILE *ptr, *file;
    int c;

    s1 = "wmic.exe /node:";
    s2 = " computersystem get username 2> nul";
    command = s1 + entry + s2;
    temp = command.toLocal8Bit().constData();
    cmd = temp.c_str();

    file = fopen("buffer.txt", "w");

    if(!file){
        this->setErrLvl(3);
        return "ERROR";
    }

    if((ptr = popen(cmd, "r")) != NULL){
        while (fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, ptr) != NULL){
            fprintf(file, "%s", buf);
        }
        pclose(ptr);
    }
    fclose(file);

    std::ifstream input("buffer.txt");
    c = 0;

    if(!input){
        this->setErrLvl(4);
        return "ERROR";
    }

    while(!input.eof()){
        std::getline(input, line);
        if(c == 1 && line.size() > 1){
            input.close();
            entry = QString::fromUtf8(line.data(), line.size());
            return entry;
        }
        c++;
    }
    input.close();
    std::remove("buffer.txt");
    return "Could not return Username.";
}
```

Like i said: just a tad on the extremly unpractial side.

The methode gets a QString with the IP-Address, combines it with `wmic.exe /node:` and  `computersystem get username 2> nul` and writes the output from wmic.exe into a text-file, reads the required line (the second), shortens the string to the necessary information and returns said information (the User-name)

Now my problem is the following: This is all fine and dandy if i just want to get one username or so during runtime... which i don't. I need to fill an entire table (containing up to 200 or more entries, depending on network activity) which takes somewhere between 10 to 15 minutes.

Now my program handles getting the IP and computername collection via sockets but i'm new to this type of programming (tbh: i just started C++ coming from C and i never did any network-related programming stuff) so i'm not that deep in the matter.

Is there a way to get the currently logged in username on a remote computer via socket?

Comment: *"**the** currently logged in username"* - That's something, that doesn't exist. At any given time, 0 or more users can be logged into a computer. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to acomplish a "simple" support tool for our company's network that allows us (the system-administrators) to see which user is logged in at which machine (so aside from system-sided users needed to run services, all i need is the currently active domain user on each machine in my network). While it is true that there are more than just one specific user is logged in, only one domain user should be active (aside from terminal-servers, but that's not important since they (as well as other servers) are filtered out of my list.

Comment: Or at least something along the lines of `wmic.exe /node:10.0.1.123 computersystem get username 2> nul` would achive but without opening a CMD for every single IP hand to the methode (which it currently does). The 10.0.1.123 is just for generally showing how the command would work and is not what actually is send to the method.

Comment: I stopped reading the code after variables named `s1`, `s2`, `temp`, `ptr`, and `c`.  Use meaningful names next time.

Comment: The computername could be the DNS name, but there are other computer names that are OS-specific, and do not necessarily match the DNS name. That is the problem with the username. There is nothing like DNS for a user, and it is OS-specific.

Comment: @RonMaupin: While i'm aware that a user is "logged" differently in other OS, OS-specifics aren't really my concern here since the tool itself is just for use in our network and we only use windows, so i am just interested in getting a Windows-Username. Like i said in my question, i already have a working method to get what i desire, it's just not as effective as i wish it to be (it basically calls wmci.exe with the parameters, writes them into a text file and reads and then returns the username).

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Thanks for the input, i'll try to improve the naming in the future.

Comment: The Windows user name has nothing to do with network protocols. It is OS specific, and things like ethernet, IP, TCP, UDP, etc. are completely unaware of any such thing. The other point I was making is that you can use networking to get the DNS name, but that may or may not match something like the Windows computer name. You really need to distinguish what you can get from network protocols vs. what you must get from the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QProcess` to handle wmic.exe tool like this:

```
void NetworkHandle::getUserName(QString entry)
{
    QProcess *wmic_process = new QProcess();
    wmic_process->setProgram("wmic.exe");
    wmic_process->setArguments(QStringList() << QString("/node:%1").arg(entry) << "computersystem" << "get" << "username");
    wmic_process->setProperty("ip_address", entry);

    connect(wmic_process, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, SLOT(parseUserName(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)) );
    wmic_process->start();
}

void NetworkHandle::parseUserName(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus)
{
    QProcess *process = dynamic_cast<QProcess*>(sender());
    if (exitStatus == QProcess::NormalExit)
    {
        qDebug() << "information for node" << process->property("ip_address").toString();
        qDebug() << process->readAllStandardOutput();
    }
    process->deleteLater();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, sorry for not aswering sooner. I can't get it to work though, get an error `No matching function for call to 'NetworkHandle::connect(QProcess*&, const char*, NetworkHandle*, const char*)'  connect(wmic_process, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, SLOT(parseUserName(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)) );` but that's probably just because i don't have any slots yet, so i'm going to test that out this week.